# How to access keys from firebase realtime db flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to access this data from Firebase realtime db :

[image]

this is the reference :

```
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('uids/$uid/sessions');
```

this is my code :

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: ref,
                itemBuilder: ((context, snapshot, animation, index) {
                  var object = snapshot.children;
                  var length = object.length;

                  for (final jsonObject in object) {
                    debugPrint("Length -- > ${length.toString()}");
                    debugPrint("Key --> ${jsonObject.key.toString()}");

                    return Column(
                    );
                  }

                  return Container();
                })),
```

and this is the output of it :

```
I/flutter (21670): Length -- > 6
I/flutter (21670): Key --> 10:20
I/flutter (21670): Length -- > 3
I/flutter (21670): Key --> 2:16
```

If it is showing length to be 6 and 3 why then it is only printing out ONLY the first key and not every key. I can't solve this issue. Can anyone suggest what should I do?